# Jackal robot PS4 remote cannot pair using bluetooth with the robot?

Tags: ros, bluetooth, clearpath, jackal, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got a jackal robot with a PS4 remote. According to the instructions it should automatically pair with the jackal robot however the pairing doesnt happen.

However, when I connect the remote to the USB inside the robot it works. Almost seems like I need to reinitialize the remote. I tried following the commands:

sudo sixpair
sudo sixad --boot-yes

I get the following error: No controller found on USB busses. Please connect your joystick via USB.

Any advice?

---

Trying ds4drv-pair command. I get the following error:

Scanning for PS4 controller
Found controller with address: 'AC:FD:93:E2:C2:0A'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 102, in 
manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in **init**
self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
'su', (bus_name, flags)))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
message, timeout)

dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/bluez-test-device", line 17, in 
manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"), "org.bluez.Manager")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in **init**
self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
'su', (bus_name, flags)))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
message, timeout)

dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240210/jackal-robot-ps4-remote-cannot-pair-using-bluetooth-with-the-robot?/) by [Ashwin Mathur](https://answers.ros.org/users/27579/ashwin-mathur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-07-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-07-23**:
I don't have a fix, I just wanted to say that I also just received a jackal and the same thing happened to me. I ended up using a different controller connected to my laptop.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-07-23**:
Did you receive it with a PS3 or PS4 controller?

**Comment by [Ashwin Mathur](https://answers.ros.org/users/27579/ashwin-mathur/) on 2016-07-23**:
I received it with a PS4 controller

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-07-24**:
Ashwin, did you get a chance to try re-pairing it with `ds4drv-pair`?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-07-24**:
Airuno2L, did you also get a PS4 controller?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-07-25**:
I got a PS4 controller but never got it working. Once I realized it wasn't working as described in the manual  I threw it in storage and grabbed a controller I'm more familiar with. The manual is incorrect else where also, like it said the robot's IP was 192.168.1.1 but it was actually 192.168.1.11

**Comment by [Ashwin Mathur](https://answers.ros.org/users/27579/ashwin-mathur/) on 2016-07-25**:
Airuno2L, you are correct there are many discrepancies in the clearpath manual, but clearpath also sent us a "From the desk of the Robotsmiths" document which helped clear alot of the confusion created by the default clearpath manual.  (Aside from the PS4 controller issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clearpath was able to assist me in solving this issue. Here are some of the things which could help solve your issue:

Firstly if you have sixad installed when you received your jackal then that needs to be removed using: sudo apt-get purge sixad

Unpair the controller: sudo bluez-test-device remove AC:FD:93:E2:C2:0A

Ensure that bluetooth is enabled: connmanctl enable bluetooth

Check to make sure bluetooth is enabled:    sudo service bluetooth status

If bluetooth is not enabled start the bluetooth: sudo service bluetooth start

Also make sure the bluetootd is executable: ls -la /usr/sbin/bluetoothd

If not make it executable: sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd

Restart the bluetooth: sudo service bluetooth restart

Finally, press the PS and share button simultaneously so the controller bluetooth is enabled for pairing and type:
sudo ds4drv-pair

Hopefully that helps!!

---

Originally posted by [Ashwin Mathur](https://answers.ros.org/users/27579/ashwin-mathur/) with karma: 26 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-07-29**:
Thanks for this. What do you mean by "search button" though?

**Comment by [Ashwin Mathur](https://answers.ros.org/users/27579/ashwin-mathur/) on 2016-07-29**:
Apologies Airuno2L, i meant to say share button.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-07-31**:
Thanks for posting this Ashwin.